# Is it possible to advertise multiple ip addresses for a manager node?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

Let's say I want to initialize a new swarm from a machine that sit between two sub-networks, 10.0.0.0/24 and 192.168.0.0/24, with address 10.0.0.1 and 192.168.0.1.

Now I have one worker node with address 10.0.0.2 and another with 192.168.0.2.

To avoid future potential errors, I want to advertise my manager node with both addresses 10.0.0.1 and 192.168.0.1 so that if something happens, my worker node will try to reconnect to the address in the sub-network they are in.

How can I do that ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that is not possible , as sited in the Docs:

> --advertise-addr
>
> This flag specifies the address that will be advertised to other
>   members of the swarm for API access and overlay networking. If
>   unspecified, Docker will check if the system has a single IP address,
>   and use that IP address with the listening port (see --listen-addr).
>   If the system has multiple IP addresses, --advertise-addr must be
>   specified so that the correct address is chosen for inter-manager
>   communication and overlay networking.
>
> It is also possible to specify a network interface to advertise that
>   interface’s address; for example --advertise-addr eth0:2377.
>
> Specifying a port is optional. If the value is a bare IP address or
>   interface name, the default port 2377 will be used.

[source](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/swarm_init/#--advertise-addr)

Comment: So, does that mean that every node of a swarm must be on the same sub-network for it to work properly ?

Comment: you need to setup yor network for swarm , you can following this : https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-overlay/ - short answer no they must not be on the same network but you need to make sure that routing and firewall rules are setup in the right way

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that